# Creating an array of tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

Suppose I have two tensor variables each of size 2x4:

```
v1 = tf.logical_and(a1, b1)
v2 = tf.logical_and(a2, b2)
```

Instead, I want to store these in an array called `v` which is of size 2x2x4. How do I do this in Tensorflow? The idea would be something like this:

```
for i in range(2):
  v[i] = tf.logical_and(a[i],b[i])
```

How do I initialize `v`? I tried initializing `v` as a numpy array which did not work. I also tried initializing it as a tensorflow variable, ie. `tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))` but that does not work either.

Note, `a` and `b` are dynamic inputs, ie. they are `tf.placeholder` variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tf.pack() is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: How would I store each tensor `v[i]` because I want to run it through a for loop and there might be more than 2 tensors.

Comment: put the v[i]s in a normal list, pass the list as the first arg to tf.pack(myListOfTensors)

Answer (score 0):

As a potentially relevant update, [in TensorFlow 1.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration) `tf.pack()` was renamed to [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack).